# How can it be that if I click on rawimage it's getting the right file name from the hard disk ? I don't understand it

Tags: unity, c#

In this script once only I'm getting the all the files from the hard disk type png images.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SavedGamesSlots : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject saveSlotPrefab;
    public float gap;

    private Transform slots;
    private string[] imagesToLoad;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        imagesToLoad = Directory.GetFiles(Application.dataPath + "/screenshots", "*.png");
        slots = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Slots Content").transform;

        for (int i = 0; i < imagesToLoad.Length; i++)
        {
            var go = Instantiate(saveSlotPrefab);
            go.transform.SetParent(slots);

            Texture2D thisTexture = new Texture2D(100, 100);
            string fileName = imagesToLoad[i];
            MouseHover.savedGameFName = fileName;
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
            thisTexture.LoadImage(bytes);
            thisTexture.name = fileName;
            go.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = thisTexture;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

At this line I'm doing reference from another script to a public static variable:

```
MouseHover.savedGameFName = fileName;
```

Then in the `MoueHover` script that I'm using it calling it from each raw image event trigger I'm using also the mouse button down:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MouseHover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SaveLoad saveLoad;
    public SceneFader sceneFader;
    public RawImagePixelsChange rawImagePixelsChange;
    public static string savedGameFName;
    public static string folder;
    public static bool loadingwithfolder = false;

    private bool loadGame = false;

    public void OnHover()
    {
        Debug.Log("Enter");
        rawImagePixelsChange.modifyPixels(0.3f);
        PlaySoundEffect();
        loadGame = true;
    }
    public void OnHoverExit()
    {
        Debug.Log("Exit");
        rawImagePixelsChange.restorePixels();
        loadGame = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(loadGame)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame = false;
                loadingwithfolder = true;
                folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(savedGameFName);
                StartCoroutine(sceneFader.FadeAndLoadScene(SceneFader.FadeDirection.In, "Game"));
                loadGame = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void PlaySoundEffect()
    {
        transform.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }
}
```

At this line :

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
```

After clicking the mouse left button inside I'm using a break point on one of the lines and I see that the variable `savedGameFName` contains the correct clicked raw image full directory with the file name, for example:

d://screenshots//screen_1920x1080_2021-01-26_18-56-46.png

But how does it know to assign to the variable `savedGameFName` the correct file name of the clicked raw image? It's not a list or something, it's just public static string variable. and the only other using is in the first script when running the game once first time.

I don't understand it.

It's working fine!!! but I don't understand how.

Comment: It looks like you've created a new user name. Would you like to [merge your accounts](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you keep access to your [previous questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/188701/39518) with one login?

Comment: Also, it looks to me like this code does not actually work. You may want to test it more thoroughly. As you've reasoned, `savedGameFName` contains the correct name for only one save file. It will be the same one for every item you click - whichever image was loaded last in your loop. If you're observing different behaviour, then it must be due to some code other than what you've shown us here.

Comment: As @DMGregory mentioned, although this script might appear to work during testing, the use of static variables means it will only work properly for one save file. This is because static variables are shared between every instance of a script, so if you set the save file name on one script, it effects every script. To fix this, you will probably want to make first change the three static variables to public or private, then add the script to your save file slot prefab. Another option is to create one OnHover script and check where the mouse is before getting file name from the prefab underneath